# How to log in into MySQL as a different user?

Tags: mysql

Could anyone help me please? I wolud like to know how to change user in MySql. That is, I created another user besides the default user root but i want to be logged in to the user account i created instead of being logged in to root automatically. Is there anyway I can do that? I've tried using MySql Console but its not working, maybe I don't have﻿ the right statements to do that. thanks

Comment: Thanks for a quick response guys. I already created the new user and given it ALL PRIVILEGES. But as soon as I open command prompt I am given to enter the password for my user (which I did't set) I hit enter and it lets me into MySql as a root user. When I exit that, it closes the command prompt and when I opet it again, it automatically says enter  the password ( for root user). How can I switch to the user that I just created? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In command prompt

> mysql -h host -u username -p

Form [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html):

> shell> mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
>
> Then type an SQL statement, end it with “;”, \g, or \G and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different user and add different privileges to user as below:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY
PASSWORD '*AAB3E285149C0135D51A520E1940DD3263DC008C';

GRANT SELECT ON database_name.table_name TO 'username'@'%';
```

And use below command to log in:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword databasename;
```