# Login in MySQL as a different user from command prompt

Tags: mysql

I already created the new user and given it ALL PRIVILEGES. But as soon as I open command prompt I am given to enter the password for my user (which I did't set) I hit enter and it lets me into MySql as a root user. When I exit that, it closes the command prompt and when I opet it again, it automatically says enter the password ( for the root user). How can I switch to the user that I just created? Thanks

Comment: stop posting multiple duplicates of the same question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764783/command-prompt-login-as-a-different-user  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763641/how-to-log-in-into-mysql-as-a-different-user

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way:

```
 mysql -u username -p databasename
```

and don't forget to remove anonymous accounts for security reasons:

```
mysql> DROP USER ''@'localhost';
mysql> DROP USER ''@'host_name';
```

Comment: I understand you. But where I can type that?? ("mysql -u username -p databasename") Because as soon as I open command prompt it says "enter password" (for the root user).

Comment: terminal in mac/linux or shell in windows. here is a bit more detailed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: @NikTerentyev, I was thinking more about it as a way of discovering about the generic usage of the "mysql" command line tool, which the user doesn't seem to be familiar with (maybe he doesn't know that it must be used with command line options and not "fire it up and then specify the user later" style). But even if you read it as RTFM, the user is IMHO in desperate need of some good RTFM :)

Comment: @Luke404 this whole site is some kind of lazy substitution for "RTFM" or "man..." =)

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have read how to use MySQL before using it, and neither to have done some research on the matter before asking your question. Remember that you are always going to write better questions if you provide details about your research, and that means you're going to get better answers.

Having said that, I think you don't know how to use the mysql command line tool, it's not something like `telnet` or `ncftp` or `EDIT.COM` that you start up and then specify details at a later time (the correct term here is *runtime*).

The prompt of the mysql tools is meant for interacting *with* a MySQL server, not to specify *which* MySQL server to interact with. That's what command line options are for, and command line options must be specified, well, on the command line: that means before actually running the command.

Please refer to [Nik Terentyev's exact and quick answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764283/300057) for the command line options you need (`-u` and eventually `-p`), and [have a look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) to the excellent and detailed [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) for generic knowledge of the tool.

While not a part of your question, please note that giving `ALL PRIVILEGES` to users could be anything from a bad habit to the worst thing to do, but it's rarely a Good Idea™.