# command prompt login as a different user

Tags: mysql

I already created the new user and given it ALL PRIVILEGES. But as soon as I open command prompt I AM GIVEN TO ENTER THE PASSWORD FOR MY ROOT USER (which I did't set) I hit enter and it lets me into MySql as a root user. When I exit that, it closes the command prompt and when I opet it again, IT AUTOMATICALLY SAYS ENTER THE PASSWORD ( for the root user). How can I switch to the user that I just created? I know (mysql -u username -p databasename) but where can I type this??? Because I am automatically given to enter the password for the root user in command prompt. 
Thanks

Comment: Do't post multiple questions...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763641/how-to-log-in-into-mysql-as-a-different-user

Answer (score 0):

if you open command prompt ( Win+'R' -> cmd.exe -> OK ), you may need to change your directory to where your mysql executable is located (or add it to your PATH), but you will be able to enter the command as you mentioned yourself.

Comment: Thanks ajcurana, could you tell me how to change my directory to where myqls executable is located? Thanks